# Can I get into a US CSE PhD if I don't have a good CGPA?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, united-states, grades

I am currently pursuing Masters (M.Tech) in CSE from IIT Madras. But my Master's CGPA is not so good. It is around 6.1 in out of 10 scale. Scoring here in [IITs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_Institutes_of_Technology) is really really difficult. I have an interest in research though my final year thesis is not yet published and chances of it being published in a Top Tier conference is very less according to my advisor. So is there any chance that I can get into at least top 100 US schools for PhD in CSE and even in interdisciplinary fields if possible?

I have a very good Bachelor's CGPA of around 9.2 out of 10 scale.

Instead of USA what other options do I have? And what about the funding? Any help will be GREAT as I am eager to do a PhD, rather than joining a job.

And last of all, does IIT tag matter?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does the admissions process work for Ph.D. programs in the US, particularly for weak or borderline students?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/38237/how-does-the-admissions-process-work-for-ph-d-programs-in-the-us-particularly)

Comment: there is no chance in hell